# Is there an easy way to get the currently active dialog on the stack?

Tags: node.js, botframework

My bot is based on core-bot sample and has an interrupt function which can be invoked by certain intents during dialogs. If I'm in a dialog, and then the interrupt starts a dialog, they are both invoked via `dc.beginDialog` and there are on a single level in the dialog stack. For example, it would look like this

`[ { id: 'viewOrderDialog', state: { dialogs: [Object] } },
  { id: 'interruptDialog', state: { dialogs: [Object] } } ]`

So I can somewhat easily get the active dialog by getting the ID of the last element in the array. However, in my process I can start additional dialogs from, in this case, interruptDialog. Those are started from within a waterfall via `step.beginDialog`. In that case, they are no longer at the same level as the other dialogs (started from dc instead of step). I have to get into `state.dialogs.dialogStack` to find the id, which then can become nested again if that dialog calls another. Here is an example of what `dc.activeDialog` can end up looking like:

`{"id":"interruptDialog","state":{"dialogs":{"dialogStack":[{"id":"waterfallDialog","state":{"options":"expediteOrder","values":{"instanceId":"d61d748e-af45-cea0-9188-63904de21dfc"},"stepIndex":0}},{"id":"escalationDialog","state":{"dialogs":{"dialogStack":[{"id":"waterfallDialog","state":{"options":{},"values":{"instanceId":"6e755278-d636-dd76-3b47-eb43e3eda1c7"},"stepIndex":2}},{"id":"emailDialog","state":{"dialogs":{"dialogStack":[{"id":"waterfallDialog","state":{"options":{},"values":{"instanceId":"87f08019-ff59-ce03-ccab-7914fb0b553b"},"stepIndex":1}},{"id":"emailPrompt","state":{"options":{"prompt":"Which email address do you want us to reply to?"},"state":{}}}]}}}]}}}]}}}`

I could get down to the lowest level, which in this case is emailPrompt, but it seems it would take an inordinate amount of overhead to check and see if each level of dialogs/dialogStack was an array. (And yes, I should probably name my waterfall dialogs something other than waterfallDialog). I was hoping there would be an easy way to just get the most recent dialog off the stack, but I couldn't find anything to give me that information.

In a less general sense, I'm specifically trying to add a condition to the interrupt to prevent it from being invoked within certain dialogs. I have a step where user can write an email body, and if they write something about expediting an order, the interrupt is activating. In this specific case I decided to solve it by converting dc.activeDialog to a string and then checking to see if it includes 'emailDialog'. Then I add a condition for `!activeDialog.includes('emailDialog')`. Works fine for this case, but I asked the more general question because this may not be a good solution in other cases where I need to know which dialog I am in.

I can provide code snippets if needed, but the code itself isn't really important. I'm just trying to determine the best way to get the id of the currently active dialog from the dialog context.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing nested dialog stacks is because you're using [component dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-compositcontrol).

If your interruptions are always performed on the root dialog context and that's where your interrupt dialogs get added, then there should be no need to dig into the nested dialog stacks. Because the interrupt dialog will always be in the root dialog stack you can just check your root dialog context to see if the active dialog is an interrupt dialog.

I don't know of any builtin way to determine the innermost active dialog, but if that's really what you want to do then it shouldn't be hard to create a recursive function to do it:

```
getInnermostActiveDialog(dc) {
    var child = dc.child;

    return child ? this.getInnermostActiveDialog(child) : dc.activeDialog;
}
```

It should be noted that the Core Bot sample makes only specific dialogs interruptible by having them extend a [common base dialog class](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/dialogs/cancelAndHelpDialog.js) and then handling interruptions from within the dialog instead of from the bot class. You might want to follow that example by having dialogs "opt in" to interruptibility rather than having the interrupt dialog "opt out."

Comment: The code snippet is what I was looking for, though I understand your suggestions here and on the other SO issue regarding changing the overall implementation. I will check the new Core Bot sample and see if I can figure out how to adapt what I've done to the new method. If I have additional questions I'll add to the issue on GitHub.